# Directory of the page a file is included in

Tags: php

I am including a page in the directory `all` with the function `basename(__DIR__)` which is in the directory `inc`, so `echo basename(__DIR__);` returns the directory `inc`, instead of directory `all`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can we see your code !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, the best way is define some specific constant in file that placed in all folder and then included into other?

```
define('ALL_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```